# BigQuery: Convert table to new structure with dummy variables

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Suppose the following Google Analytics-related query (see below).

I need to dummy code the column 'Channel', so that a separate column is needed for each unique value and convert to 0 and 1 values.

For standard SQL, does anyone know how to achieve this in standard SQL language?

Please note that the query below is just used as an example. There are queries where I need to dummy code which are more complex, and where simple CASE WHEN statements are not sufficient to generate the 'dummified' result.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT device.deviceCategory AS Device, channelGrouping AS Channel, SUM(totals.visits) AS Sessions
FROM `[project_id].[dataset_id].[table_id]`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) # previous 13 weeks
  AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))  
GROUP BY Device, Channel
```

Example,suppose the following table (for illustration purpose, in CSV-format):

```
Device,Channel,Sessions
Desktop,Organic,25
Desktop,Paid,30
Desktop,Affiliate,14
Mobile,Organic,26
Mobile,Paid,66
Mobile,Affiliate,70
```

Desired result:

```
Device,Organic,Paid,Affiliate,Sessions
Desktop,1,0,0,25
Desktop,0,1,0,30
Desktop,0,0,1,14
Mobile,1,0,0,26
Mobile,0,1,0,66
Mobile,0,0,1,70
```

Comment: Why can you not use _case when_ statements ?

Comment: In some cases I have 100+ unique values. Next to this, from time to time new unique values could be added over time. I need a more dynamic solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some specific rule to classify your field as 1 or 0 based on your table's data, you could use something like this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN field in (SELECT distinct value from <your-table> WHERE <classification-rules-for-1> ) THEN 1
    WHEN field in (SELECT distinct value from <your-table> WHERE <classification-rules-for-0> ) THEN 0
END
```

Is it suitable for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not sufficient. This requires manual coding of 0 and 1 values. It could be that in my table in the future more unique values will be added to the column. With your method, I have to manually add these values to the query, which is not an acceptable solution. I'd like to dynamically convert all available unique values in the column without all the manual WHEN THEN code, but with a piece of dynamic query code.

Comment: What is your rule to classify the values as 0 or 1?

Comment: Each unique value in the column which should be 'dummified' should in the desired situation get a separate column with 0 and 1 values. In the description above, I added an example to clarify.